# Angular `@Input()` type is `undefined` in runtime

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-cli

I have a Angular component, And I add a `type` to the Input property with `namespace` as follow code.

`@Input() size: AMap.Size`

`AMap` is a `namespace` and the class `Size` with in. The IDE and typescript compiler work well.But, It's not work in browser。 And throw an error of

`Uncaught ReferenceError: AMap is not defined`

I found the compiled code

[image]

Why the type will compile into the code?

The `AMap` types as follow

```
declare namespace AMap {

    export class Size {}

}
```

thanks

Comment: that `AMap` namespace, is yours? I mean, belongs to your project, or comes from an external library

Comment: @OscarPaz Yeah, It's mine. and in my project.

Comment: Can  you show us the code of the file in which it is defined?

Comment: The file is in `src/types/amap/index.d.ts`, And the config of `tsconfig.json` is
 ```
"typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "src/types"
    ]
```

Comment: Yes, but, can you post the contents?

Comment: I added the code fragment in the question body.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was using a type alias at the top of the file and then using that.

```
type ASize = AMap.Size

...

@Input() size: ASize
```

I know that this is only a workaround, but maybe it is of use to someone.

Comment: I don't like this solution but it did the trick for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I think that was related to Typescript, webpack bundling issue. Can you try to use:

```
export module AMap {
   export class Size {...}
}
```

instead of export namespace.
And import it and use in component like:

```
import { AMap } from './../..';
```